# How many cells are in prophase on this onion root tip slide?

Tags: cell-biology, plant-physiology, mitosis

In the following image, I have to identify the cells in the different phases (not counting the cells that are too faded to see), and it's fairly easy to identify metaphase, anaphase, and telophase, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right for prophase vs. interphase.

I try to see if there's a nucleolus or not, but sometimes it's difficult. When I counted, I got 7 cells in prophase. Is this close to what you guys see or am I way off?

Thanks!

[image: Onion root tip slide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard call on early prophase versus interphase, especially since these are not natural distinctions with discrete boundaries but are used to articulate a continous process.

I'd say you're pretty close, I count six for sure. That includes the one in the top row on the far left that is partially clipped in the photo. One iffy possibility is in the third row just left of the obvious anaphase on the left.

Unless your teacher is far more particular than I was with students, I think you're good to go.